# Mongodb: Getting sub document directly as root

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using projection I am getting the sub document but under the key, not as root.

Current query:

```
db.collection.find({"userId" : {"$ne" : userId}, "gender":{"$in" : interestedin}}, {"profile" : 1, "_id" : 0})
```

Which returns like this:

```
[{"profile":{"firstName":"Payal",...}},{"profile":{"firstName":"Ravinder",...}}...]
```

What I need is:

```
[{"firstName":"Payal",...},{"firstName":"Ravinder",...}...]
```

I am asking this question to confirm there exist something like this or not, as I found something of relevance here:     https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/

But, it uses aggregation framework.

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "......."
    },
    "id": ".......",
    "facebookId": "......",
    "email": "......@.....com",
    "gender": "....",
    "interestedIn": [
        "....."
    ],
    "isPrivate": false,
    "profile": {
        "name": {
            "firstName": "....",
            "middleName": "",
            "lastName": "....."
        },
        "picture": "........",
        "dob": 1111138064533,
        "meta": {
            "education": [],
            "interests": [],
            "music": [],
            "movies": [],
            "tvSeries": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your sample document in the question, it will help others to understand better

Comment: @ClementAmarnath See the edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) operator to promote nested object to root level, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {"userId" : {"$ne" : userId}, "gender":{"$in" : interestedin}} },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$profile.name"
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

@mickl answer is going in the right direction, but I want to complement his answer as his syntax is wrong.

Use `$replaceRoot` to promote a document to the top level. It **only works with object** so you want to use `$unwind` to extract your array data before promote nested object:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {"userId" : {"$ne" : userId}, "gender":{"$in" : interestedin}} },
    { $unwind: "$profile"},
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$profile"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks to both of you, but accepting@mickl's answer as he answered first :)